# Is Privileged Access Management secured without regular Patch Update?

Tags: password-management, pam

It is well know Privileged Access Management (PAM) is a solution that helps organizations restrict privileged access within an existing Active Directory environment.
Many big company use it to address their Privileged Access.
The issue is PAM solution system normally advice customer not to Patch their Operating System because it will some sort impact their system.
Is this secured?

Comment: Any patching may affect security. This is, as in other cases, a matter of balance. Does patching break more than it fixed ?

Answer (score 1):

> > > PAM solution system normally advice customer not to Patch their Operating System

This does not sound correct and I would suggest calling out the PAM vendor and looking into their competitors. I've never heard of a PAM vendor telling their customer they should avoid patching the OS. Sounds like a poor PAM vendor or a miscommunication